# Heroku with Docker - ERROR H14:No web processes running

Tags: node.js, docker, express, heroku, pm2

I'm trying to deploy a simple nodejs app served in express and Pm2, via a Docker container on Heroku.

Following the steps defined by heroku, the container is sucessfully pushed to heroku:

1. heroku container:login
2. heroku container:push name-of-container -a name-of-herokuApp
3. heroku container:release name-of-container -a name-of-herokuApp
4. heroku ps:scale name-of-container=1 -a name-of-herokuApp

Here is the log of heroku showing the success on running the image and assigning a dyno to the process
[Container Deployment Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcghO.png)

Here is when the problem comes: while accessing to the apps routes the Heroku H14 Error is throw, which happens when a proccess doesn't have Dynos, which in my case it have.
[Error H14 Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fDIo.png)

I'm out of ideas as the reason this error is raising. I know it might be a silly mistake thought XD!!

Here you got the code for my app:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
//require('./database')


app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
console.log('App is Running, yaaaay') 

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send("OK")
})

app.listen(3000)
```

and its run with Pm2:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/app",
    "start": "pm2-runtime ./src/app.js --watch --name WD-Bot"
  },
```

Also, here you got my DockerFile. I'm pretty newbie on Docker, so i probably messed up on here T-T?

```
FROM node:12.18-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 6):

You did:

> `heroku container:push name-of-container -a name-of-herokuApp`

You assume that's the name of the container. That's wrong. As per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#build-an-image-and-push that's the process type:

> `heroku container:push <process-type>`

The error message you are receiving is:

```
ERROR H14:No web processes running
```

You named your process `wd-bot` and not `web`.

After changing your process type to `web` you'll have to properly bind the `$PORT` as well. See: https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error
But that's a different topic and is a new question.

Comment: I ran into this problem just now, and this solution (using 'web' after 'push' instead of the docker image name) solved my problem. Thanks!